# Swift UNavigationItem button display menu labels

Tags: swift, button, uinavigationcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I'm new in Swift and I would like to how to do this.

When I touch `rightBarButtonItem` button I would like the following to appear:

[image: Behavior when button touched]

The **Test** and **Test2** text should display **in the same view controller**.

If I don't touch `rightBarButtonItem` the **Test** and **Test2** should not display. (**Test** and **Test2** `isHidden` will be `true`.)

[image: Behavior when button not touched]

Is this possible or do I need another way?

I have been searching for a long time on the internet. But I have not been able to find anything. Please help or try to give some ideas of how to achieve this.

Comment: Please note that Apple discourages you from using hamburger menus such as this. They prefer tab bars.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman Apple has approved thousand of apps these years using hamburger menus, following the hamburger menu Facebook style's. How do you read these informations?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano It's not that they're against the guidelines, they just aren't preferred.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman Ah, ok, I didn't understand you. Interesting. How do you know about it?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano It was the just the impression I got from this WWDC 2014 session around 35:25 minutes in: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/211/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, you can add `Test` and `Test2` in a `view` or `stackView`, then change the isHidden property of the view.
but as Matthew said, apple prefer to use tab bars.

set the view isHidden property to true in ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customView.isHidden = true
}
@IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!

@IBAction func rightBarButtonClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    customView.isHidden = !customView.isHidden
}
```

you can also use [SWReveal](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) pod.

or you can create it by yourself in swift using this [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) document